# How to pass props to component in same file?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-props, react-typescript

I want to pass the value of **width** to the component **Color** from component **Scala** as prop. But I am getting an error width is not defined, or width not found. Can someone help me. This is a tsx file (typescript)

```
const Scale = (props: any) => {
  const brewer = props.brewer;
  let Length = props.Length; //accepting value from colorlegend <- flowlines
  if (Length == 0) {
    let width = 1;
  } else {
    let width = Math.floor(120 / Length);
    console.log(width);
  }

  const colors = getColors(chroma.scale(brewer), LENGTH);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: 30,
          fontSize: '1.5em',
          textAlign: 'right',
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}
      >
        {brewer}
      </div>{' '}
      {colors.map(Color)}
    </div>
  );
};

const Color = (color: any, props: any) => (
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundColor: color,
      width: props.width,
      height: 15,
      display: 'inline-block',
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: `getColors` is not defined as far as i can see?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the return value of the `map` function:

```
colors.map(color => <Color key={color} color={color} width={<specify-a-width>});
```

You should also consider the `color` as a component prop

```
const Color = (props: any) => (
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundColor: props.color,
      width: props.width,
      height: 15,
      display: 'inline-block',
    }}
  />
);
```